# Cannot replace all ^ symbol to 25%5E

Tags: javascript, reactjs, str-replace

I have replace the problem in react. I want **^** to **25%5E**, but I just can replace one of **^** in the string, cannot replace all **^** symbol to **25%5E**. Below is my sample code:

```js
var urlStr = "http://localhost:3005/branch-management/edit-branch/?companyName=ABC%20SDN%20BHD%20!!!!%40%40%40%40%23%24%^%26*()&branchName=ABC%20!%40%23%24%^%26*()_";
var newUrlStr = urlStr.replace("^", "25%5E");

console.log(newUrlStr);
```

Error Result:

[image: img]

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [`replaceAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) which is for replacing all matched strings

```js
var urlStr = "http://localhost:3005/branch-management/edit-branch/?companyName=ABC%20SDN%20BHD%20!!!!%40%40%40%40%23%24%^%26*()&branchName=ABC%20!%40%23%24%^%26*()_";
var newUrlStr = urlStr.replaceAll("^", "25%5E");

console.log(newUrlStr);
```

You also can use regex with `/g` ([a global flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/global)) to have similar behaviour

```js
    var urlStr = "http://localhost:3005/branch-management/edit-branch/?companyName=ABC%20SDN%20BHD%20!!!!%40%40%40%40%23%24%^%26*()&branchName=ABC%20!%40%23%24%^%26*()_";
var newUrlStr = urlStr.replace(/\^/g, "25%5E");

console.log(newUrlStr);
```

Answer (score 1):

use `regex` to find all occurence of `^` and replace.

```js
var urlStr = "http://localhost:3005/branch-management/edit-branch/?companyName=ABC%20SDN%20BHD%20!!!!%40%40%40%40%23%24%^%26*()&branchName=ABC%20!%40%23%24%^%26*()_";
var newUrlStr = urlStr.replace(/\^/g, "25%5E");

console.log(newUrlStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `replaceAll()` method

```js
var urlStr = "http://localhost:3005/branch-management/edit-branch/?companyName=ABC%20SDN%20BHD%20!!!!%40%40%40%40%23%24%^%26*()&branchName=ABC%20!%40%23%24%^%26*()_";

var newUrlStr = urlStr.replaceAll("^", "25%5E");

console.log(newUrlStr);
```

the replace method either takes a pair of char's or a pair of CharSequence's (of which String is a subclass, so it'll happily take a pair of String's).

The replace method will replace all occurrences of a char or CharSequence. On the other hand, the first String arguments of replaceFirst and replaceAll are regular expressions (regex). Using the wrong function can lead to subtle bugs.